# How to get the instance of the Entity Manager in FOSUserBundle Controller

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

I am using FOSUserBundle in Symfony 2.3, I created an additional table for store the user profile, at some point, I need to access to the entity manager to persist and flush the data coming from the profile form to the profile table, but I am having problems trying to get an instance of the entity manager.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details? eg. your entities, controllers, configuration of FOSUserBundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit profiles of users using the FOSUserBundle, you have to create a new ProfileController which extends the ProfileController of FOSUserBundle.

Here you can now override methods of the FOSUserBundle.

An exemple of start :

```
<?php

/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ProfileController as BaseController;

/**
 * Controller managing the user profile
 *
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class ProfileController extends BaseController
{
   public function editAction()
   {
     $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
     // your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: This could probably be dealt with better using an [Event|Subscriber]Listener. The ProfileController of the FOSUserBundle throws out multiple events that you can listen to, and therefore affect the object (User), without needing access to the Entity Manager as the entity hasn't been flushed by yet. More info is probably needed.. For example in the following the method gets the object, changes it and moves on, with no need for the Entity Manager.. https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/CoreBundle/EventListener/OrderPromotionListener.php

Answer (score 2):

You can access to the Doctrine service this way :

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

The controllers of the FOSUserBundle extend from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware`. So you have access to the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface` through `$this->container`. With this container you can access doctrine and subequently the EntityManager:

```
$doctrine = $this->container->get('doctrine');
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```